Can't inspect values in playwright debugger
I'm using NodeJS playwright in my project and I'm trying to leverage the Playwright inspector to understand the values returned in the locators. But I'm struggling to do so because the inspector isn't giving me a way to interact with the content being executed. The playwright docs show me a version of the inspector that has a Pick Locator option, which isn't available in the inspector I'm getting.
I've upgraded to the latest version of Playwright (1.43.0) but still nothing. I do get a Locator tab at the bottom, as shown on the picture, but when I type in it nothing appears.
I'm using Chrome.
This is what I'm getting

This is what I expect

Does anyone know what I could have set wrong?

Second button from the left is the pick locator button. The docs are showing an older UI.

Thanks...But I didn't manage to interact with the content unfortunately..I managed to do better debug using the debug mode through the chrome inspect tool.

I initially had the same issue as you, and couldn't find the "Pick Locator" tab in the Playwright Inspector.
If you click on the button on the right of the "Record" button in Playwright Inspector, then it activates the "Pick Locator" feature and then you can select the web element on the webpage you want to find the locator for.
Then, the locator will display in the Playwright Inspector, under the "Locator" tab.
Although, I found that the locators provided are with methods like, "getByLabel" and "getByText". Not just the locator itself.
For Example:
getByLabel('Username:')
getByText('Incorrect username/password.')
Hope this is helpful!
